# jest doesn't apply scss styling during test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, sass, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a button component, but I'm unable to check its color since the scss styles are not being applied during testing. Instead, the default value is used. Here's the code I'm using:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "white"
Received: "ButtonFace"

53 | console.log(buttonStyle);
54 | const backgroundColor = buttonStyle.getPropertyValue('background-color');
> 55 | expect(backgroundColor).toBe('white');
   |                                 ^
56 | });
57 |
58 | });
```

I tried using the jest-transform-scss package to resolve this issue, but it requires node-sass, which cannot be installed on my M1 computer.

When I run the Jest command, the received value is "ButtonFace", which is the default background color for a button. How can I check the styling value during testing?

You can find the repository with the code here: https://github.com/Merwan1010/jest-scss

To run the tests, simply run yarn install followed by yarn test.